# Allow access to files only from 1 script/location

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is it possible to use .htaccess or similar to stop files in a folder from being accessed via http however to allow access to the files if called via a specific page/script? I want to make sure the only access to the files is if a user is logged-into their account where links to the protected files will be available. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Put the files that you want to restrict the access to out of `public_html` and use them within the scripts. This way, that files will not be able to be accessed directly.

Answer (score 0):

Just put such files **outside** from the webserver root, and access them via a protected resource route.